# How to add check box inside combobox in c#

Tags: c#, combobox, checkbox

I want to add check box inside comboBox in C#. My purpose is that the user can select multiple values from one ComboBox (  Check all and Uncheck all ).

Please Help

Comment: are you so limited in space like this? how many checkboxes would there be ?

Comment: @ariel : I want to bind from database.

Comment: This is really not a good idea. Users don't expect to see checkboxes in a combobox. Use one of the other controls explicitly designed for this, like a `CheckedListBox` or even better, a `ListView`.

Comment: I understood its not good idea but i have seen this in some other application and i dont know how they implement that so   have asked this question.

Comment: Owner-drawing. Essentially your code takes over all responsibility for drawing the combobox, instead of letting the system do it. This follows the general rule that the more unusual something is, the harder it is to implement correctly. That's a good reason not to use it unless you *absolutely* have to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to extend the ComboBox control by providing your own rendering strategy, and "manually" adding a CheckBox.

Theses open source project are ready to use :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/CheckComboBox.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/extending_combobox.aspx

Answer (score 4):

It is a wrong usage of a ComboBox control, because the user has no possibility to see his choices. For multiple selection, I recommend you to consider this CheckedListBox control:

[link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There is an ASP.NET open source control at http://dropdowncheckboxes.codeplex.com/ that I've used and been very happy with. There is also a WinForms open source control at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/extending_combobox.aspx that doesn't look quite as strong but maybe somebody could combine the best of both. If well implemented this is really a great addition to your toolkit. The above 2 implementations show all of the items selected and give you a number of related checkboxes in a reduced area and with excellent grouping. My addition to the ASP.NET version was to allow a list of checked files to use just file names instead of full paths if this gets too long. See above link for full code. Below is just my addition which is called instead of UpdateSelection in your postback handler:

```
// Update the caption assuming that the items are files 
// If the caption is too long, eliminate paths from file names 
public void UpdateSelectionFiles(int maxChars) { 
  StringBuilder full = new StringBuilder(); 
  StringBuilder shorter = new StringBuilder(); 
  foreach (ListItem item in Items) { 
    if (item.Selected) { 
      full.AppendFormat("{0}; ", item.Text);
      shorter.AppendFormat("{0}; ", new FileInfo(item.Text).Name); 
    } 
  } 
  if (full.Length == 0) Texts.SelectBoxCaption = "Select..."; 
  else if (full.Length <= maxChars) Texts.SelectBoxCaption = full.ToString(); 
  else Texts.SelectBoxCaption = shorter.ToString(); 
}
```